# org-mode / export to PDF: How to disable numbering for pages?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When I export a simple text file to PDF with the command `org-latex-export-to-pdf`, by default, Org-mode adds the number of each page at the bottom of the PDF file.

But I would like Emacs to print absolutely no page number.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{nopageno}` to the top of the document.

Comment: or `#+latex_header: \pagestyle{empty}`

Comment: @Dox that does not work completely if you for example have `book` as the documentclass.  Hence the dedicated package is better (even though its code is only 4 tokens!)

Comment: @AndrewSwann: HAHAHA... Sure. Thank you! I will take your advise